# Are expressions like "x axis," "x dimension," "x direction," "x plane," "x boundary," etc. all hyphenated?

Tags: coordinate-systems, terminology, soft-question, geometry

I'm not a native speaker of English. I'm currently writing a journal article and want to make sure I follow all conventions properly. Are expressions like "x axis," "x dimension," "x direction," "x plane," "x boundary," etc. all hyphenated or not?

Comment: This would be better asked to a language forum than a physics site.

Comment: @Triatticus Like [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/). However, that depends on whether there are people over there that specialize in answering questions about technical writing intended for English-language journals. In my writing I will hyphenate some of them and not others, and I'm not sure that I'm consistent.  No journal editor has ever commented on my usage, and I don't think they were edited in proofs. That said, journals always have style guides, so look there first.

Comment: It depends on the style guide (or, more generally, the consensus practices of one's field). I edit for the Springer–Nature and Elsevier journal families. One style guide might maintain, for example, that "axis" always gets a hyphen, whereas the others are up to the author as long as consistency is maintained. This gives you a sense of the arbitrary nature of punctuation conventions. If the style guide is unhelpful, I suggest following the practices of your favorite textbook on the subject of interest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be more about the English language than physics,